How to retrieve values and calculate average from a dimension table based on selected multiple values in a slicer, and use default value if not found
I'm developing a dashboard which is composed of some business fields as attached :

there is the census related configuration for each facilities,
As you can see, Census data is available only for a subset of facilities.

and my goal is to put a "Y-Axis Constant Line" on a graph with the average value of "AnnulaBudgetLevel" as a user selects facilities like:

Here are more details I'd like to implement

with the average "AnnulaBudgetLevel" for selected facilities
there is another indicator for the enterprise level, [prmEnterpriseABL], and it's 0.9406.
** FYI, PBI shows 0.9374 as an overall average of [AnnulaBudgetLevel] for all census facilities.
** User wants to change the value of [prmEnterpriseABL] dynamically, it's implemented as a parameter.
when a user opens this dashboard, [prmEnterpriseABL] is supposed to display (assumes selected ALL facilities).
when a user selects facilities whose [FacilityId] is not 'view_FacilityBudgetConfig', those facilities can be ignored on calculating the average.
if a user selects facilities which do not match at all with 'view_FacilityBudgetConfig', then [msrEnterpriseABL] is expected to display.

I tried to put some measures

prmEnterpriseABL (parameter) = 0.9406
msrAvgABL = Average( [AnnulaBudgetLevel] )
msrSelectedABL = ... (will share it later)

My problem is

I can't pick [prmEnterpriseABL] when I open a dashboard
or when I choose all facilites on a Facility slicer

I tried with DAX expression as below,

when I open a dashboard
or select all facilities
"Y-Axis Constant Line" displays as 0.9374(overall average) not 0.9406([prmEnterpriseABL Value]).

msrSelectedABL =
VAR SelectedFacilities = VALUES( 'CORE view_Facility'[FacilityName] )
VAR FacilityBudgetValues =
    SELECTCOLUMNS( FILTER( 'HOUSING view_FacilityBudgetConfig',
                           'HOUSING view_FacilityBudgetConfig'[FacilityId] IN SelectedFacilities ),
        "AnnualBudgetLevel", 
        'HOUSING view_FacilityBudgetConfig'[AnnualBudgetLevel]
    )
VAR BudgetCount = COUNTROWS( FacilityBudgetValues )
RETURN
    IF(
        BudgetCount = 0 || COUNTROWS( SelectedFacilities ) = 0,
        [prmEnterpriseABL Value],
        AVERAGEX( FacilityBudgetValues, [AnnualBudgetLevel] )
    )

Please guide me what I'm doing wrong with my DAX expression.
